# Swift - Get the parent of a Realm object; Always empty

Tags: swift, realm, parent-child

I've got a relationship where:

> A `Parent` has many `Children`

ie:

```
class Factory: Object {
public let engines = List<Engine>()
}

class Engine:Object {
private let parents:LinkingObjects<Factory> = LinkingObjects(fromType: Factory.self, property: "engines")
    var parent:Factory? {
        return self.parents.first
    }
}
```

I read the factories via JSON and create the children (Engine) manually in a for-loop, similar to this:

```
var engines:[Engine] = [Engine]()
for _ in stride(from:0, to: 3, by: 1) {
let engine: Engine = Engine.init()
engines.append(engine)
}
return engines
```

In my test I want to query the parent of a given engine to ensure that the parent is correct; or perhaps get a parent attribute.

However, whenever I try to grab an attribute via the parent its always empty;

```
for (_, element) in (factories.enumerated()) {
  for (_, eng) in element.engines.enumerated() {
    print (eng.parent ?? "N/A" as Any)  // Always prints out N/A
  }
}
```

Ideally I want to be able to access the parent's data; like the name of the parent, perhaps costs, etc.

I've tried resetting simulator and also deleting derived data; but regardless of what I do the results are always N/A or empty.

How can I query the given element and ensure that I can grab the parent data?

Many thanks

Comment: First thing I would use the Realm browser app to see if the objects and relationships are correctly saved in the Realm DB.

Comment: I will try to use the Realm browser app to do as you state. The thing is, I'm using the XCTest area and the Realm is set as in-memory.  I can switch it off and try it again anyhow.

Comment: Many thanks, i was able to ascertain that I was not writing any objects to memory; also there was a lot of other bugs and issues relating to XCTest that I had not anticipated and had to fix them too.  I've seen the data being written in the realm browser but noticed that there is lots of data in there when I know there should be a certain number.  I will investigate further on my own time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there were a number of issues that I had to do to resolve this.

I was using XCTest and Realm was causing issues where there were multiple targets.

1. Make all my model classes' `public`
2. Remove the models from the test target, this included a file where the JSON data was being loaded into memory
3. I had to write my data into Realm, which I had not done;

   ```
           let realm = try! Realm()

           try! realm.write {
               for parent:EYLocomotive in objects {
                   for _ in stride(from:0, to: parent.qty, by: 1) {
                       let engine : EYEngine = EYEngine.init()
                       parent.engines.append(engine)
                   }
                   realm.add(parent)
               }
            }
   ```